# Best free Git GUI client for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, git

Since all the Git GUI client questions are closed and there is no way for me to share this gem I found after abandoning my search and using Git CLI for a few months, I am creating a question and will answer it myself. I want somebody to be able to Google this and find the perfect answer.

Comment: I'll recommend [RabbitVCS](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/about). It has plugins for common [graphical](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/about/screenshots) [file-managers](https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs#clients).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app is [Sublime Merge](https://www.sublimemerge.com/download) from the makers of Sublime text editor and it is amazing! It's available in Ubuntu as a snap package. To install the Sublime Merge snap package run:

```
 sudo snap install sublime-merge --classic
```